# Running a python package using Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am very new to Python Data Analytics.

I was asked to look at this package in Gitlab https://gitlab.com/imda-dsl/intelligent-sensing-toolbox and
https://gitlab.com/imda-dsl/intelligent-sensing-toolbox/blob/master/demo/Intelligent%20Sensing%20Toolkit%20Tutorial/Intelligent%20Sensing%20Toolbox%20Tutorial.md

I saw some commands:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./energydata_complete.csv', index_col='date', parse_dates=[0])
df.head(3)
```

I am interested to run them and I have downloaded Anaconda and installed.  Can those command above be ran in Jupyter?  I am very new to Data Analytics and your guide on how I can start to run those demo data will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will run fine in Jupyter most python packages run perfectly in Jupyter.